# Trying to get XML value from Stringbuilder String - C# (Moneris Data Preload)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, stringbuilder

I am writing a code to pull a specific value from Stringbuilder.
The idea is, I am submitting a form to Moneris - A payment gateway (I am using a sample key and id so there is no confidential information is mentioned in here) to receive a dynamically generated key from Moneris.

**Please see my code below:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<html>");
    sb.AppendFormat(@"<body onload='document.forms[""form""].submit()'>");
    sb.AppendFormat("<form name='form' action='{0}' method='post'>", "https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php");
    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='ps_store_id' value='{0}'>", "R6SXStore3");
    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='hpp_key' value='{0}'>", "hpZPXLXZNBLF");
    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='charge_total' value='{0}'>", "2.00");
    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='hpp_preload' value='{0}'>", "");
    sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='{0}'>", "");
    sb.Append("</form>");
    sb.Append("</body>");
    sb.Append("</html>");

Response.Write(sb.ToString()); // This is submitting the above form to the moneris (third party payment website and throwing values in a kind of XML format).
```

Please see the screenshot https://snag.gy/OHbk6y.jpg of what response i am getting from Moneris.

I am interested in pulling value from "ticket" node which i have highlighted in the screenshot above.

This is a code i am writing to pull value from "ticket" node.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//  string myXML = @"<!--?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?--><html><head></head><body><response><hpp_id>R6SXStore3</hpp_id><ticket>hpp1529956212E2mefmVB93Yu2taJy</ticket><order_id></order_id><response_code>1</response_code></response></body></html>";
string myXML = sb.ToString();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(myXML);
XmlNodeList parentNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("response");
string xticket;
string xhpp_id;
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in parentNode)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("ticket").InnerText);
    }
Response.End();
```

**Error:**

When i run above mentioned code, i see this error: 
Please see the screenshot https://snag.gy/PJMKqL.jpg

However, when i un-comment my code where i am passing a hardcoded value in the variable "myXML" then i get my result perfectly. The hardcoded value is what i am pulling from browser's source code when i get a response from Moneris.

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm confused - it looks like you're parsing your request XML (with form tag, etc), and not the response that you're getting back from Moneris. Where do you actually hit the Moneris service and get back the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a WebClient to do that. I've also added a few lines to work over SSL, if you need it.

```
public void test()
    {
        var postData = "ps_store_id=R6SXStore3";
        postData += "&hpp_key=hpZPXLXZNBLF";
        postData += "&charge_total=2.00";
        postData += "&hpp_preload=";
        postData += "&order_id=";

        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php");
        myRequest.Method = "POST";
        myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        //This code is to work using SSL
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

        //Post the content
        var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        //Read the response
        var response = myRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        var result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

        responseReader.Close();
        response.Close();

        //Your original code
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(result); //Load the response into the XML
        XmlNodeList parentNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("response");
        string xticket;
        string xhpp_id;
        foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in parentNode)
        {
            xticket = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("ticket").InnerText;
            xhpp_id = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("hpp_id").InnerText;
        }
    }

    public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```